# How to alter a dataframe in the cycle inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, cycle

I'm trying to make a function that takes the column list `cols` and performs `get_dummies` for each.
The thing is that if I use cycle only that works fine. But if I try to make a function out of it, the dataframe remains unchanged.

The function:

```
def cols_to_dummies(df, cols: list):
    for c in cols:
        temp_dum = pd.get_dummies(df[str(c)])

        df = pd.concat([df, temp_dum], axis=1)
        df.drop(str(c), axis=1, inplace=True)
        del temp_dum
```

The usage:

```
cols = ['column1', 'column2']

cols_to_dummies(df, cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

concatenating the two frames, creates df variable inside the function, so it loss reference with the outside df. A simple way to solve your code is to have a return frame.

```
def cols_to_dummies(df, cols: list):
    for c in cols:
        temp_dum = pd.get_dummies(df[str(c)])

        df = pd.concat([df, temp_dum], axis=1)
        df.drop(str(c), axis=1, inplace=True)
        del temp_dum
    return df
df = cols_to_dummies(df, ['num', 'user'])
```